# How do I implement a tappable label in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to swap my submit button to a tappable label. What is the best way to go to achieve this or is this even possible using Xamarin.Forms? Currently this is the code I have for my button:

```
 async void SubmitFeedback_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ExtendedGrialButton btn = sender as ExtendedGrialButton;

      if (btn.IDValue != IDofSymptomforAdjusting)
      {
           await DisplayAlert("Add feedback", "Please add feedback for the symptom selected", "OK");
      }

      else if (rangeSlider == null)
      {
           await DisplayAlert("Add feedback", "Please add feedback for a symptom", "OK");
      }
      else
      {
           await AddSymptomFeedback(rangeSlider.IDValue, rangeSlider.Value.ToString());
      }
 }
```

Currently this is my label code :

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource FontIcon}"
       TextColor="#8472AF"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       HeightRequest="160"
       WidthRequest="160"
       FontSize="60"
       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
       x:Name="SymptomIcon"
       Margin="0,0,0,0"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Grid.RowSpan="4"    
       Grid.Column="2" />
```

Is it possible for me to add a label tapped gesture that will allow me to do this? I'd like to remove the button from my app and just use the label with a tapped gesture to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to your `Label`. Do it like this:

```
<Label ...>
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SubmitFeedback_Clicked" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: I get an error with this line now if i try this code ; if (btn.IDValue != IDofSymptomforAdjusting)

Comment: If you remove the button, which is referenced in `btn`, then you will need to do some refactoring, yes. The `sender` will now be the `Label` control

Comment: How would i do that now ?

Comment: That is a bit hard to say. I don't know what `btn.IDValue` is, but it seems it is an extra property of the button. What you could do is create your own inheritance of a `Label` and add a similar property. The logic would then remain largely the same. But again; I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so this is really just guessing.

Comment: That did it , thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of service! Be sure to mark it as the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Gerald answer isn't wrong but if you want to do it programmatically, can do like this

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += async(s, e) => {

      //your code
    };
    SymptomIcon.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
}
```

Comment: True! I just assumed it should be XAML since his Label is showing XAML :)